# Change a highchart subtittle

Tags: php, highcharts, label

Is it possible to change the X axis labels of a highchart to include a decimal separator?

My X axis has the following values 10000,20000,30000 I need to convert to 10.000,20.000,30.000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `format` option in the [docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels)

[Example appending km to the axis points](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/yaxis/labels-format/)

[Example formatting to 3 decimal places](http://jsfiddle.net/11t2a0a7/)

Comment: But how do I manipulate the value to insert the coma in between? I really have no idea. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, the comma in between?

Comment: Ignore my comment I am tired of working. Issue solved. Thanks!

Comment: By the way I meant thousand separator. God I should go home.

Answer (score 0):

Thousands separator and one decimal place: {value.y:,.1f}